# Biolinum in memoir's chaptitlefont?

Tags: fonts, memoir, libertine

For `pdflatex` i use:

```
\documentclass[openany,twoside,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                        
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}                                                          
\usepackage[russian,ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{libertine}

 % ...

\makechapterstyle{chapter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\Large\bfseries}
}
```

But I get CMR in titles instead of Biolinum.

My `libertine`'s version is 2017/03/22.

Comment: Please add a full MWE that we just have to copy/paste to get compiled. What if you load libertine afer redefining chapter style ? Just an idea.

Comment: There is no support for Cyrillic in Biolinum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following example

```
\documentclass[openany,twoside,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                        
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}                                                          
\usepackage[russian,ukrainian]{babel}

\usepackage{libertine}

\makechapterstyle{chapter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\Huge\sffamily\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\Large\bfseries}
}
\chapterstyle{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Кирилиця}

\end{document}
```

LaTeX issues the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/LinuxBiolinumT-TLF/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 18.
```

There is no support for Cyrillic in the Linux Biolinum font family for `pdlatex`. There is only for Linux Libertine.

You can choose another sans serif font having support for Cyrillic, such as `opensans` or `PTSans`. Try loading

```
\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans}
```

or

```
\usepackage{PTSans}
```

*after* `\usepackage{libertine}`.

Comment: However with xelatex I have both libertine and biolinum. So, there is no Cyrillic in the Linux Biolinum T1 fonts, OTF is ok?

Comment: @brownian Yes, that's it.

Comment: yes, `locate libertine | grep T2A` shows me the point. Thanks!